# Reading files from directory, Object not found

Tags: r

I have a total of 100 ".csv" files in my directory. They are named as "1.csv","2.csv" etc. I assigned all those files to a vector x as follows

```
x<-list.files(path=getwd(),pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
```

Next i wanted to read those files as data frames for which I used read.csv() function. I wanted to simultaneously read a number of csv files. Therefore I wanted to assign it to a variable f.

```
 id<-5:7
for(i in seq_along(id)){
        f[i]<-read.csv(x[id[i]])   }
```

but i get an error saying that

```
Error in f[i] <- read.csv(x[id[i]]) : object 'f' not found
```

Comment: What is `f` (`str(f)`)?

Comment: You have to define `f` first.

Comment: what class of object does f belong to? Each f[i] is a data-frame. I tried to define it as f<-list(length(id)). But it is not working. How do i define it?

Comment: @jogo  f(str(f))  returned an error as Error: could not find function "f"

Comment: @PatrickLi  how do i define f?

Comment: yes, that is clear, because `f` not exists. Eventually you want `f <- lapply(x[id], read.csv)`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
x <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern = ".csv",full.names = TRUE)
for (i in length(x)){    
for (j in unique(x)){
         paste0("f", i) <- read.csv(x[j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i got it 
i had to define f in order to use it inside for loop

```
 f<-list()
                for(i in seq_along(id)){
                f[[i]]<-read.csv(x[id[i]])}
```

this will work fine!!!!